# Is there an abbreviation to denote "f***k You?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, slang, abbreviations

I frequently see people using various facebook expressions in official e-mails or in general text message.

What bemuses me is that most of the time ""F***K you" is written/put as "f**K you".
Please pardon my jarring mind, but FKU is not what I think is an abbreviation.

Is there an abbreviated form that has come into usage?

Comment: GFY, GTFO, RTFM, FY, FU, WTF, GAFD ... I'm sure someone at Urban Dictionary has made a case but why it would be officially answerable by English Language Experts is another issue altogether.

Comment: *Is there an abbreviated form that has come into usage?*  Probably hundreds, no doubt including some emoticons.

Comment: Military persons will usually comprehend "foxtrot uniform"  Not sure how well it translates outside the military, however.  Also more of a euphemism than an abbreviation, which is why I offer as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Of course, there's the non-verbal sign language for f-you (raised middle finger).

Comment: 4Q ... There're "Cs" of them, http://www.internetslang.com/4Q-meaning-definition.asp T4P-Thanks For Posting

Comment: @KristinaLopez - That's what that means???  (I always thought it meant "I love you!")

Comment: @HotLicks You mean it doesn't mean, "You're number 1!"?

Comment: What, pray tell, are “facebook expressions”, and why are they not appropriate in “general text message”? And what exactly do you mean that “F\*\*\*K you” is written as “f\*\*K you”? Are you asking why some people use an uppercase F and three asterisks, while most people use a lowercase f and only two asterisks? And what’s with the uppercase K (which is lowercase in the title)? Also, why is FKU not an abbreviation? It is short for both _Friedrichshain-Kreuzberger Unternehmerverein_ and _Fyns Kran Udstyr_. I find this question most puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

"FU" is a fairly common abbreviation for that particular phrase.  The "F" standing for the offensive word, and the "U" standing for a phonetic representation of the word "you".

There are...a number of other colorful "F"-related acronyms that pertain to this saying, but I don't think a full list of them is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

> F you

Is quite popular, and slightly less offensive than spelling the word out. This abbreviation can be spoken aloud: "Eff you".